# How to format a closed Excel sheet using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

I have sheet1.xls which is closed. I am working in sheet2.xls VBA as follows.

```
With Range("A:XFD")
 <I need Some Code here to format entire sheet1.xls cells into string format> 
End With
```

Kinldy help.Thanks

Comment: Maybe you need to explain what formatting you want? Give an example or describe what changes you want to do.

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro and looking at the resulting code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will allow you to format the closed book. It is opened and then formatted and then closed again.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub Format_Closed_Sheet()
    Dim sht1book As Workbook
    Dim sht1ws As Worksheet
    Dim strValue As String
    Dim rng As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    With Application

    '--> Open sheet1.xls
    Set sht1book = .Workbooks.Open _
    ("Path to Sheet1.xls")
    End With

    Set sht1ws = sht1book.Sheets("Sheet1")

    '--> Format the range as text

    Set rng = sht1ws.Range("A:XFD")
    rng.NumberFormat = "@"

    '--> Save sheet1.xls and close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    sht1book.Save
    sht1book.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it:

```
Dim b As Workbook
Dim sh As Worksheet

Set b = Workbooks.Open("C:\mypath\mybook.xls") ' or wherever your workbook is

Set sh = b.Sheets("Sheet1") ' or whatever sheet
sh.Cells.NumberFormat = "@" ' format as Text

b.Close
```

If you want to format *all* of the sheets in your workbook as text, you can do this:

```
For Each sh In wb.Sheets
    sh.Cells.NumberFormat = "@" ' format as Text
Next sh
```

Comment: Its working but asking "Do you want to save changes to mybook.xls" ? I want it to be auto saved. Is there any script to save automatically. THanks

Comment: i Just said, No more comments needed as i have got from above answer . . Any way Thanks for your reply

Answer (score 0):

Just declare a workbook and sheet:

```
dim oBook as excel.workbook
dim oSheet as excel.worksheet

set oBook = workbooks.open("<workbook path and filename>")
set oSheet = oBook.sheets("<SheetName>")
```

then:

```
with oSheet.range("A:XFD") 
     <Format>
end with
oBook.close
set oBook = nothing 
set oSheet = nothing
```

And so on.

Comment: application.screenupdating = false if you don't want to see the update happen. It is to my knowledge not possible to change things without opening the workbook.