# ScreenUpdating not working when opening a file

Tags: macos, vba, excel

So I'm creating a library of commonly used macros for excel for my Excel 2011 for Mac. I'm running a couple of tests to make sure it's working properly. The biggest problem I'm running into is that when I run the code (despite having ScreenUpdating set to False), it visibly opens the library file while it runs the macro.

To make sure this is efficient going forward, I want to prevent that from happening. Here is currently what my code looks like:

```
Sub findRow()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableEvents = False

Dim bk As Workbook
Dim result As Long
Dim aWB As Workbook
Dim aWS As Worksheet
Set aWB = ActiveWorkbook
Set aWS = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    .EnableEvents = False
Set bk = .Workbooks.Open _
(ActiveWorkbook.Path & ":library.xlsm")
'Set bk = ActiveWorkbook.Path & ":library.xlsm"
End With

'Workbooks.Open (ActiveWorkbook.Path & ":library.xlsm")
'Workbooks.Open (bk)
result = Application.Run("'" & ActiveWorkbook.Name & "'!findFirstEmptyRow", aWS)
ActiveWorkbook.Close
Cells(result, 1) = result

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

There is quite a few redundancies in there as well as commented out lines that show various things I've tried. Originally I simply ran code that set Application.X settings to False, opened the Workbook, ran the macro, and closed.

Hopefully someone can come up with a reason for ScreenUpdating not taking effect when I open a new Workbook.

Comment: Check `findFirstEmptyRow` for `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` (or the Workbook_Open() sub)

Comment: Paul, findFirstEmptyRow row does not have that line. I don't have a Workbook_Open() sub.

Comment: Check if there is a `Workbook_Open` event in `library.xlsm` which may be setting `Application.ScreenUpdating = False`

Comment: Again, there is no Workbook_Open event that I know of. I certainly didn't create one. Further when I checked the ThisWorkbook module in VBA, I didn't find any code there. Also, wouldn't you want that function to contain the line `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` if it wasn't already? Second, Shouldn't `Application.EnableEvents = False` automatically block the event `Workbook_Open()` event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting ScreenUpdating to false only prevents spreadsheet updates from showing. It wont on its own hide the opening of a workbook.  Although there are ways to hide the opening of a workbook, or access workbook data without creating an instance of Excel, for the task you're describing of creating a VBA library, the way to go about that is to create an Excel add-in.  An add-in not only allows you to use a macro from any instance of Excel, but you can also edit your code and add new macros to a common repository from any instance also.

Comment: While I'm fine with experimenting with different Add-Ins, if you have a recommendation for one that suits well, it would be awesome. Also, any chance you know what the difference is between [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469215/vba-to-add-new-sheet-in-a-closed-excel-without-opening-get-the-sheet-name-adde) and my own situation is in regards to the answer by Alistair Weir?

Comment: What I'm saying is create your own add-in.  I'm not talking about an add-in  for you to get, you can save your VBA code as an .xla or .xlam from the saveas drop down list.  Excel will default save it to your add-ins directory.  Add this newly created add-in to your add-in references and away you go.