# Copy and add a sheet to a closed workbook

Tags: sql, vba, excel

Using SQL I can access and edit cells in Excel workbooks without opening them in a vba script. However I have not yet found a way to copy or add a sheet in a similar way. Atm I use Workbook.Open and Copy to accomplish it. Is this possible?

Comment: You have just posted a question tagged with excel-vba to ask if there's a way to do something without vba?  Also take a look at these guidelines for writing a good SO question: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/

Comment: Well its still in VBA but using SQL queries with ADODB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the same problem and searched for hours until found this one using ADODB-Connection Object:

```
path= <yourFilePath>
set cn = new ADODB.connection

'create connection String
connStr="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; & _
        "Data Source=" & path & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;"";ReadOnly=0'"

cn.Open connStr
set cmd = new adodb.command
cmd.ActiveConnection = cn

'create sql-string
cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE [<TableName>] (<anyString> char(255))"
cmd.Execute
```

see: [VBA to add new sheet in a closed excel without opening & get the sheet name added?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11473356/10883689)

I think that's what you and everyone else who stumble about this post is looking for.

Further you can create a String `INSERT INTO [<TableName>$] VALUES('<values>')` to add some data to the sheet.